# Unity 3D - Collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, collision

I have a problem with physics. It is my first time doing in 3D, so it may be just a beginner mistake.

I just wanted to create a simple player controller and make it so that it can not pass trough cubes.
The problem is that when going straight into the cube, part of the player is in the cube itself. When stop moving, it pushes me, so they are not intersecting (that makes sense).

I tried moving the player using .Transalte, .MovePosition and by changing the velocity of rigidbody itself. None of it change anything. The player can always move a part of him into the cube.

Any ideas how to solve this?

My player controller:
(The 2 lines commented out in Move() are just other ways to move the player.)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
   private float movementSpeed;

   private Vector3 input;

   private void Update()
   {
      GetInput();
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      Move();
   }

   private void GetInput()
   {
      float inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
      float intputVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
      input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(inputHorizontal, 0, intputVertical), 1);
   }

   private void Move()
   {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += input * movementSpeed;
      //GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position + input * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
      //transform.Translate(input * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
   }
}
```

[Player is standing still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kwOO.png)

[Player is moving towards cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rIa8.png)

[Settings of the Game Objects itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvqMt.png)

Comment: You can check unity documentation, its quite useful.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/CollidersOverview.html
Many times I had problems because at least one of the 2 members of the collison has to have the rigidbody component. You can check that out

Comment: @RustyBucketBay Both of them do have rigidbody

Comment: I dont know the shape of your player controller, so as fat as I can guess maybe the graphic part of the asset is not corresponding to the collider. You can you a mesh collider  to have a collider adjusted to the mesh renderer. Sorry for the basic suggestions, but it would be useful to know the components of the 2 gameobjects involved in the collision to discard many of the things that could happen

Comment: I just added a capsule with collider and rb. Same with cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think I understand your problem.

The collider is a geometric shape that is checked but the outcome wont take place until the collision has actually taken place, this means, one geometric shape being inside the other. By this I mean, that what you are experiencing is the normal behaviour of the collision. If both elemnts are rigid bodies, both will move and your problem wont be perceivable, but if your cube is not a rigid body or is kinematic, will stand still in the same position, and depending on the other object speed, its normal that an invasion/superposition of the elements is perceivable, because that is the frame were the collision took place, and were your element needs to be moved back because it has collided.

Consider that if the speed is high enough, and the position from one frame to another varies enough, the collision might not even take place, because the geometric parts do not interfere between frames, as the position variation might be bigger than the bounds of the collider itself. The collision check at the end of the day, is dicrete, and not continuous (even you can set it as continuous to be as frecuent as possible).

To solve or improve that, you can adjust the speeds to avoid that being perceivable + adjust your collider to make it react before the graphic superposition occurs. This means making the capsule or the cube collider bigger than the graphic element itself. You can even calculate , to make it as bigger as much as your your speed * Time.deltaTime result or speed * FixedTimeStep result, depending on your safety distance needs. I think one of those should be the safety distance you need to take into account before the graphic collision occurs.

Another thing you can do is tight more the times physics calculations are done.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

[image: time settings]

But need to be careful with this as this can be a performance devourer and need to be handled with care. You can make some trials with that and check your problem can improve.

Hope that helps

Comment: Great, thanks. I will use the cube as kinematic, since I can change it when I need it to be affected by physics. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the scale of your player's collider from the Collider component attached to it. You can check how big the collider is from the editor scene view.

Edit: The issue might be that your movement or collision code is called in `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate`. When working with rigidbodies, you want to call the physics calculations inside `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: That won't really solve it. Now basically part of the player collider intersects with the box collider when moving into it. When I stop, it pushes me out of the box.
If I increase the scale of it, it will just make it impossible to stand right next to the box without having to moving into it.

Comment: I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: I do use `FixedUpdate`. I added my controller to the question.
Actually when I use just `Update` the player is kind of jittering. The problem I am having with the interstecting is pretty smooth.

Answer (score 0):

remove rigidbody from the cube, you can click on 'Gizmos' in the top right of the editor and make sure the colliders are at the edges of the objects.